# Значение слова "рухлядь"

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

Известно, что изначально словом **рухлядь** обозначали пушнину. Но как вышло, что в современном языке это слово приобрело совершенно противоположное значение?

Answer (score 1):

Совсем не противоположное.
В основе слово "рухло" - имущество. Ценное оно или нет - вопрос вторичный.

Я вот подумал, рухлядь можно вынести на свалку. Но после этого она перестаёт быть рухлядью, становится просто хламом. Рухлядь - это что-то такое из домашней или офисной мебели, загромождающее помещение. За его пределами - уже что-то иное.
(Субъективное восприятие).

Answer (score 1):

Не просто "рухлядью" называли пушнину, а "мягкой рухлядью".  Думаю, всё объяснит значение слов "рух",  "рухло", "рухлявый". См. ниже.

"Мягкая рухлядь", название пушнины в 15 — начале 18 вв. в России. "М. р." выступала не только как товар, но и как денежный эквивалент. Использовалась царским правительством в виде пожалований и наград служилым людям и иноземцам.
***Яндекс.Словари › БСЭ***, 1969-1978

***Словарь М.Фасмера***:
Рух Ближайшая этимология: "**суматоха**, волнение, тревога", укр., блр. Рух "***движение***", чеш., слвц., польск. ruch "*движение*". Отсюда Руґшить. Дальнейшая этимология: Ср. лит. ru«us "***деятельный***", ruo«us -- то же, ru«e†ґti "быть деятельным", лтш. ru°oss "***подвижный***, деловой", rusenis "рыхлый снег", лит. ruo~«ti, ruo«iu° "готовить, снаряжать", ruo«a° "приготовление", шв. ru^sа "вырываться", ср.-в.-н. ru^sch м. "нападение", д.-в.-н. ro^sc, ro^sci "**ловкий, поспешный**, свежий"; см. Траутман, ВSW 241; М.--Э. 3, 563, 582; Лескин, Abl. 308; Зубатый, ВВ 18, 264; Перссон 838. Далее связано с лат. ruЎ "обрушиваться". См. также Рыґхлый, Руґшить, Руґхлый. Страницы: 3,524
Слово:Руґхло Ближайшая этимология: "движимое имущество", Руґхлядь ж., др.-русск. Рухло, Рухлядь, укр. Руґхло -- то же, Рухляґвий "подвижный, проворный". Связано с предыдущим; см. Мi. ЕW 285; Преобр. II, 227. Страницы: 3,524

Comment: нсколько помню, изначально (задолго до 15 века) меха бмли имеено "рухлядью". "Мягкая" пояаилось уже с расширением значения слова.